# Bash function, for files in folder conditional chmod (permissions) setting

Tags: bash

Case is, inside `/var/www/html` need to write function for changing all FILES (recursive, but not folders) `chmod` depending on their already set one:

```
function fm664 {

# define parent, see if it is within apache localhost
pdir=$(dirname "$PWD")

if [ $pdir = "/var/www/html" ]; then
  for file in "$PWD/*"
  do
  fp = $(stat -c "%a %n" $file);
  echo "$fp"
    if [ "$fp" -lt 664  ]
      sudo chmod 664 $file
      # echo to see what it outputs
      echo "stat -c "%a %n"";
    fi
  done
fi
}
```

Seems not goona work, on refining (`source ~/.bash_profile`) says ERROR ..
What's wrong ?

Comment: This looks like a usecase for the [`find` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html). Check out the `-perm` and `-type` tests, as well as the `-exec` action.

Answer (score 1):

### Issues With The Current Script

There are two syntax errors and some hidden bugs in your script:

- Assignments only work without spaces around the `=`.
  Write `fp=$(...);`instead of `fp = $(...);`
- The `if` statement is missing its `then`.
- In `for file in "$PWD/*"` the `*` should be unquoted, or else the loop will have exactly one iteration with `file=./*`.
- `[ "$fp" -lt 664  ]` will probably fail, since `$fp` contains not only a number, but also the file name. Remove the `%n` from `fp=$(stat -c "%a %n" "$file")`.

After fixing these issues, [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) your script to fix smaller issues.

### Hints

If you want to stick to your current approach, have a look at bash's globstar option (`**`) to list all files recursively.

A better alternative would be the `find` command and its `-perm` and `-type` option (as pointed out in the comments). You can use `find` to list and filter all files recursively. There is also an `-exec` option that lets you execute a command for each file, so that you don't have to loop manually over the output of `find`.

### Suggested Solution

Did you really want to check `[ "$fp" -lt 664  ]`? If some file had the permission `700` its permission would not change. I think you just wanted to ensure, that all files have *at least* read/write permissions for the user and read permissions for group and others.

The following command does exactly that:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod u+rw,go+r {} \;
```

Comment: You mean `"$file"` rather than `$file`, surely.